# Discretization by column for large data sets in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to discretize a pretty large set of numerical data in R (30-50 cols, 500k-1M rows) using the `RWeka` package.

my original code looked like this:

```
disc_data <- Discretize(class~., data=ndata, na.action=na.pass)
```

but I got out of memory errors. I thought it would help to call the function on only one feature at a time (actually 2 columns, to include the class), so I wrote this:

```
x <- cbind(ndata[1],ndata$class)
disc_data <- Discretize(class~., data=x, na.action=na.pass)
```

which i intended to run in some sort of loop and combine the results together. However, this gives me:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = class ~ ., data = x, na.action = na.pass) : 
object is not a matrix
```

To be clear, Discretize takes a data.frame for data, not a matrix...

How can I fix this, either by debugging or by using a better method to address the memory issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check what the column names are in `x`?

When you run `cbind(ndata[1],ndata$class)`, the second column is named `ndata$class`, *not* `class`. What you need is

```
x <- cbind(ndata[1], class=ndata$class)
```

Comment: wow that wasn't what I was expecting to be the problem at all. Thanks for the help fixing the bug!